# FrameLayout: View Arrrangement and Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-framelayout

The main highlight of my activity is the image in the center, that can be zoom in up to the whole screen. Right now, The positions are okay but in some point of zooming in the image two of the textview are being covered by the image, the rest of the view remains at the top of the image.

So my main problem is to put the two textview at the top of the image. I tried transferring the positions of each of the view in xml but for some reason I got null pointer exception.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FF4F00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:text="Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPid"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="#FF4F00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:text="Category Or PID" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemNo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSellingPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:textColor="#FF4F00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:text="Item No" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSellingPrice"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FF4F00"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:alpha=".5"
        android:text="Selling Price" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you show it graphically hows it's look like or what you have achieving ?

Comment: I added the screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Change the relative layout item ordering so that the imageview is the first item. Items are layout and drawn in the order of they appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>        android:layout_gravity="center" >
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/rl"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/layout"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="right"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txtName"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>             android:alpha=".5"
>             android:text="Name"
>             android:textColor="#FF4F00"
>             android:textSize="20sp" />
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txtPid"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"
>             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>             android:alpha=".5"
>             android:text="Category Or PID"
>             android:textColor="#FF4F00"
>             android:textSize="20sp" />
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txtItemNo"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/txtSellingPrice"
>             android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
>             android:alpha=".5"
>             android:text="Item No"
>             android:textColor="#FF4F00"
>             android:textSize="20sp" />
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/txtSellingPrice"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_below="@+id/txtPid"
>             android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>             android:alpha=".5"
>             android:text="Selling Price"
>             android:textColor="#FF4F00"
>             android:textSize="20sp" />
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout"
>         android:background="@drawable/selctor"
>         android:scaleType="center" />
> </RelativeLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

**OutPut:**

[image]